# "mode" doesn't run in python 3.5 subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I have encountered a bit of a conundrum while working on an automation project.

When I try to run:

```
program = subprocess.run("mode")
```

I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

However, when I replace mode with ipconfig:

```
program = subprocess.run("ipconfig")
```

it runs perfectly fine.

Anyone got an explanation? I am currently using a batch file to run the mode command, but I would like to change the arguments without editing a batch file.

Edit 1:

I also just tried using os.system:

```
os.system("mode")
```

and that also worked.

Edit 2:

Now I would just like answer to the original problem just to understand what was going on.

Comment: You might need `shell=True`?

Comment: @WayneWerner So I tried it with Popen and set shell to true and it also worked. Do you have any clue why it works like that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3172470/344286) it pretty much says that `shell=True` is something that you should shy away from.

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Is what tipped me off that you might want `shell=True` in your subprocess call. If the file can't be found that means one of two things:

1. It's not on your path.
2. It's not *actually* a file.

For instance, in Linux:

```
$ which echo
echo: shell built-in command
```

That makes it pretty obvious that there *is* no `echo` file. It's just a command that's built into the shell. This *may* be the same thing when it comes to `mode` on Windows. Though [this site](http://www.computerhope.com/modehlp.htm) seems to suggest that it's a `MODE.COM` file. You may try invoking *that*, as in

```
subprocess.run('MODE.COM')
```

That may work - at least according to one of [the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172488/344286) that I linked to

> Invoking via the shell does allow you to expand environment variables and file globs according to the shell's usual mechanism. On POSIX systems, the shell expands file globs to a list of files. On Windows, a file glob (e.g., "*.*") is not expanded by the shell, anyway (but environment variables on a command line are expanded by cmd.exe).

So in your case, perhaps `mode` isn't a file, but `MODE.COM` *is*, and since Windows has a spotty relationship with casing, it seems possible that by passing `shell=True`, the Windows shell happily takes `mode` and converts it to `MODE.COM` for you, but without it, it tries to execute the file literally named `mode`, which doesn't exist.